# queque system that manages load

Tags: c, daemon, unix

I need a queque system that runs as fast as possible but doesn't slow down the server.

I have a web app (php) that converts different pieces of media (photos,video,etc). When someone wants to convert a file the command to convert goes into a database. I need a program that can run the commands in a way that will not crash my server.

I need the following:

-Something that always is running on the server.
-Looks at a postgres database for new content
-Program advances to the next command in the database once the previous command has finished
-When a command finishes it updates the postgres table with either success/failure and timestamp
-The program should use as much cpu as needed but not be the priority...I want the process to be fast but I don't want have my server crawl to a stop.
-Program needs to be able to limit different programs (so if app 1 is running and someone submits for app 2...app 2 doesn't run unless the server can handle it.)

Anyone know any existing scripts available or ideas? I have played with cpulimit but that just limits it doesn't let the server use its full potential when there is no server load. I have tried -nice -n but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming question.

Comment: Couldn't it be accomplished by a C program? if it is not programming then what is it?

Comment: Why doesn't "nice" work?

Answer (score 0):

A daemon will do well.   Consider a client server model - the server dispatches conversion tasks to a child process or calls pthread_create to create a client thread to handle the task.  At the time of fork()/exec or pthread_create  you can determine the number of active clients, and hence the load on the system.  Then you can adjust priority accordingly. 
This gives you dynamic control of the resource consumption.

I fail to see why nice can not work for you. What exactly does "doesn't seem to work" mean in your context?

Comment: You know not sure why nice doesn't work. I always put -nice 19 in front of all my commands. I use FFMPEG and ffmpeg2theora. Another weird thing is ffmpeg2thoera has a nice flag I can set and that doesn't work. I say "doesn't seem to work" I mean CPU is 99-100%. Not even webpages load.

Comment: I just checked ffmpeg2thoera website and did not see a nice switch.  That doesn't matter all that much.  I would assume these programs are using lots of resources that do not necessarily have to do with CPU - memory, disk, and so on.  You need to get the commands to work from the command line before you ever try to code a daemon.  Try creating a process, then nice 19.  Now, try running your ffmpeg command and see what you get.

Comment: I think maybe I cannot run nice because it is not root. Is there a way to have it run as non root?

Comment: nice -19 INCREASES priority,  and requires root access.  nice 19 decreases priority and any user has access to it.

Comment: @jimmcnamara `nice -19` decreases priority, `nice --19` increases priority (and requires root permissions). It is a bit confusing but the first `-` is used so that `nice` understands that `19` isn't the command.

Comment: 'The nice() function shall add the value of incr to the nice value of the calling process. A process' nice value is a non-negative number for which a more positive value shall result in less favorable scheduling.'  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/nice.html

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a very nice little system that would send hundreds of thousands of emails (to users of the website) that first checked the [CPU Load average](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sys-getloadavg.php). If it was < 2.0, continue, otherwise it slept for  a few seconds and then tried again. Wrapping that PHP script was a bash-script that just ran the PHP script continually, after a brief pause.

```
#!/bin/sh
nice /usr/bin/php -f ..../phpjobs/resizeContentFromDb.php
sleep 5
# and .... restart.
exec $0
```